# How to use correctly plugin facebook comments?

Tags: html, django, facebook

I am modifying jango  [website](http://www.confiam.com.brd)  by adding facebook comment plugin.I am unable to add comments to the posts in the pages properly.

In local, the comments to  one post will be listed under all others posts as well.

base.html:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=106788150014600";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

post_detail.html

```
<div class=item>
    <p><h1>{{ post.nome_patrocinio }}</h1></p>
    <center><picture>{% cloudinary post.foto_patrocinio %}</picture></center>
    <p><h2>{{ post.apresentacao_patrocinio }}</h2></p>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href= "{{ post.patrocinio }}" data-numposts="5"></div>
    <br>
</div>
```

I didn't add a facebook comments plugin to website online yet, only locally. 
I don't know if it is necessary, but in my models I don't have a slug field.

How to do this?

Comment: you should consider using english in your code, it´s the standard language for developers. harder to help with all the italian words. what´s patrocinio? is that a unique url for each post?

Comment: It is portuguese, patrocínio mean sponsorship. Yeah, patrocínio is my views object. Sorry about my los knowledge about it. I don't have slug in my models to call the object.

Comment: I don't have unique  url for each post

Comment: The comments are tied to the URL that you point the plugin to. If you want unique “sets” of comments for different articles - then you want unique URLs.

Comment: So, have I to create another views and url? I am trying to do this, but I 'm not getting. As a blog, I am trying to create post_detail views, the problem is   that I already have created.

Comment: I have 7 views (7 defs inside views.py), have I to create one post_detail view for another page that I put the facebook comments?I want only one page to have facebook comments.